# Error Installing mysql2 using mysql connector c 6.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I Got this

C:\Users\markyosef>gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir="C:\MysqlCon
nector"
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)

## ======================================================================

\ You've installed the binary version of mysql2.
  It was built using MySQL Connector/C version 6.1.5.
  It's recommended to use the exact same version to avoid potential is
sues.

At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files were retri
eved from:
  http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-w
inx64.zip

\ This gem *includes* vendor/libmysql.dll with redistribution notice
in vendor/README.

## ======================================================================

Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32
Parsing documentation for mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32
Done installing documentation for mysql2 after 1 seconds
1 gem installed

And this is what i got when testing mysql

D:\RubyProj>ruby test.rb
Failed to load libmysql.dll from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
.6\lib

Need help with this error guys 
Thank you :D

I have xampp on my computer but i installed other mysql server version 5.6 is this okay?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows XP, I downloaded previous mysql connector lib (mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip), removed and installed gem with this connector and it worked. Perhaps the newer DLL is incompatible.